# How are java swing apps designed these days with respect to MVC architechtural pattern?

Tags: java, swing

Back in the day, say from 2001-2004 I wrote several java Swing apps( jdk 1.2- 1.4 ), before annotations were added to the language.

The way we did swing development was pretty straight forward:
create a container/component based model,  arrange components/widgits in panel containers using layout managers, add the panel container to a JFrame Container.

This approach is what they call "monolithic" app these days.

Can anyone point me to a good swing project on github that is considered "good design" and why it is a good design?

I am confused with concepts such as: annotatoins ( jdk 1.5 ), Dependency Injection, Inversion of Control containers and other frameworks/tools they may be using to facilitate proper swing applications.

Comment: I'm betting a majority of UIs are web-based these days.  Swing's day came and went.

Comment: Since web-based UIs don't  require any installation on the client side, many clients simply replaced their swing applications with web apps. Swing will slowly completely disappear.

Comment: Swing is based on MVC design, where the model view and controller are split in distinct elements, most developers ignore the controller element (the look and feel delegate) and simply focus on the model/view aspect. You can still create "monolithic" apps with MVC if you're not careful

Answer (score 1):

As noted previously, Swing is not used much presently.
However, to assist you I would recommend looking at JavaFX and, if you are interested in moving your Swing app to the web, look at Vaadin.

Comment: If you have a look at the Job market, Swing is used more the JavaFX

Comment: This was a couple years back but when I was looking for a job many of the recruiters were asking about my Swing experience or my Qt UI experience.  At the end of the day I had 3 offers; 2 swing positions and 1 QT position,  but then again I didn't have any real web development experience.

Comment: As for JavaFX versus Swing, see http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2273822